# Why won't uploaded image file be displayed?

Tags: javascript, html, image, upload

I am working on a project that requires me to display an image when it is uploaded, and I have tried several solutions to no avail (See: [option 1](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/), [option 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459379/preview-an-image-before-it-is-uploaded?answertab=oldest#tab-top)). In each case, I can get the solution to work in an independent set of test HTML/CSS/JavaScript files, but it cannot be integrated into the project. I have rewritten the HTML and Javascript of the main project a couple times, but the problem remains. What else might I try, or where else might I look, to resolve this difficulty?

Edit: To clarify – the [first option](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/) is a working solution. I can run it in an independent HTML file, and it uploads and displays images. Yet, whenever and however I attempt to use this solution in the other project, the upload appears to be successful but the thumbnail image doesn't appear. This is the case even when the exact text of the solution above is pasted in, and this is a problem I have had with other solutions. I am asking for general troubleshooting advice – what I might do to understand where it is going wrong

Edit: Now I see that the functionality is there (i.e. images display correctly) in Firefox (Version 18.0.1), but images do not appear at all in Safari (Version 6.0.2). My revised question, then, is **why would they not display in Safari?**

Comment: Very unclear what your question is: it looks like you have solution that works for you... You may try to pay someone to integrate code into your project... or at least provide much more information in the question (minimal code, clear error messages....)

Comment: To clarify – the first option is a working solution. I can run it in an independent HTML file, and it uploads and displays images. Yet, whenever and however I attempt to use this solution in the other project, the upload appears to be successful but the thumbnail image doesn't appear. This is the case even when the exact text of the solution above is pasted in, and this is a problem I have had with other solutions. I am asking for general troubleshooting advice – what I might do to understand where it is going wrong.

Comment: If your question is "how to debug issues with HTML/JavaScript" - use developer tools F12 in most browser, may need to instal Firebug if using Firefox.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Thank you for your response. I have edited my post for clarity. I cannot see what code would be appropriate to include, unless it is appropriate to include the whole HTML file (~200 lines), given that I have tried to implement the solution in numerous ways and tried to get the image to appear anywhere on my page (not just the dynamic tab I hope to ultimately place it in) and there are no clear error messages.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Thank you, I will try to debug with developer tools.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Thank you for your advice. Now I see, per my edit above, that it works correctly in Firefox but not at all in Safari.